# python - Django redirect to next after login (Generic Form View)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am using generic form view for authentication, I am getting next parameter in url but unfortunately I don't know how to redirect it to next, after successful login for Generic Form View, here is my view

```
class LoginView(
    views.AnonymousRequiredMixin,
    generic.FormView):
form_class = LoginForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
template_name = 'accounts/registered/login.html'
def form_valid(self, form):

    username = form.cleaned_data['username']
    password = form.cleaned_data['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active and user.is_seller:
        login(self.request, user)
        return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

I am getting this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/accounts/dashboard/
```

help me out!

Answer (score 1):

So essentially, what the url that you are getting means is that it's trying to go to 127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/dashboard/, but because the user needs to be logged in, it's going to the login page first. Essentially, this means that your view is not logging the user in for some reason.

Try using (or extending) Django's built in LoginForm class (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)

Alternatively, go with a broader solution suite, such as django allauth (https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/docs/index.rst)

Comment: Thanks it seems good but I when used django built in login form as you suggested, it is only redirecting to LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL but it should try to redirect the user to the next GET param, please help me out sir!

Comment: What is your LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL? Could it be missing a slash at the beginning of it? That would cause it to simply be appended to your current URL, and might well be the cause of your issue

Comment: I put, LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'  in my settings

Comment: Ok so just to confirm, when you use Django's native method, it does not go to the page you want it to go to, but to the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL? That's quite weird. Could you update your original post with your new view function, the URL you are at when logging in, and the URL it redirects you too?

Comment: It's a different question that I asked which is basically how we can redirect to next param it generic view, so I didn't edit this but created a new query, you can have a look on that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542035/python-django-built-in-login-view-not-redirecting-to-next

Answer (score 0):

You should use **HttpRedirectResponse**:

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def login(request):
    # You logic goes here
    return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard')

def dashboard(request):
    context = {
        # User information goes here
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard', context)
```

Do not forget to add this call to the login method in your **urls.py**:

```
path('login', views.login, name='login'),
path('dashboard', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

You should also take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/ for a better understanding of how request and response work.

You should also be familiar with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial04/ so that you could understand an example of **HttpResponseRedirect**.