# python - Django built in login view not redirecting to next

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am using django auth views for authentication but after successful login it should try to redirect the user to the next GET param but it is redirecting to LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL only!
here is my url

```
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'accounts/registered/login.html',}, name='login'),
```

in my setting.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

when a unauthenticated user wants to visit dashboard it automatically redirected to login page with next param

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/accounts/dashboard/
```

but after successful login it redirects it to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

it should redirect it according to next param.

Comment: Could you add in the class/function for your views.py?

Comment: Sir, I which view you want to be added, I am using login view from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views, Which is in built in django.

Comment: Ah, that might be the issue. The login view from auth.views is being deprecated. Try importing LoginView instead, which is a CBV, so in your urls.py make sure you use auth_views.LoginView.as_view()

Comment: Now I am using this url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name= 'accounts/registered/login.html',redirect_field_name='next'),
                                            name='login'),

Comment: but it still not redirecting to next param

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to add hidden field `next` to the `accounts/registered/login.html` template:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
```

Comment: The accepted answer above did not work for me, the value of the hidden field `{{ next }}` was empty. To populate the value I had to use `{{ request.GET.next}}`

Answer (score 0):

### Link to be redirected

#### template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'login_url_name' %}?next={% url 'url_name_to_be_redirected' parameter=some_pk %}">click me</a>
```

#### urls.py

```
url(r'^login/$', CustomLoginView.as_view(template_name='html/custom_login.html', extra_context={'key': 'value'}, authentication_form=CustomAuthenticationForm), name='login_url_name'),
```

### some_login_view_file.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        try:
            next_page = self.request.POST['next']
        except:
            next_page = "/"
        return next_page
```

#### custom_login.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login_url_name' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}">
   <div>
       {{ form.username }}
       {{ form.username.errors }}
   </div>
   <div>
        {{ form.password }}
        {{ form.password.errors }}
   </div>
   <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```